# how can i code public class for SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite

I am new to android and I need to use `ListView` for my project. I use a sample from the internet which has no public class for `ListView` so I am not able to code flexible. how can I code public class for this.

```
public class LIGHTS extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView users_list;
    private DatabaseManager dbManager;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    final String[] from = new String[]{dbHelper._ID, dbHelper.TITLE, dbHelper.DESC};
    final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.KEYCODE, R.id.NAME};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);
        startconnection();

        dbManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

        users_list = findViewById(R.id.users_list);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter, cursor, from, to, 0);
        users_list.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

and the fetch() is in below code in dbmanager:

```
    public Cursor fetch() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{dbHelper._ID, dbHelper.TITLE, dbHelper.DESC};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't quite understand what you are asking. What problems have you encountered with this code? What does it do when you run your app? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i am create an app that have database. client add three string to database and my listview should show two of them. and i have one switch button in Listview for every item. the difficult is switch state and i wanna change state of switches or read the state of switches and do some job.

Comment: To add click handlers to a view in the row of your ListView, you will need to create a custom Adapter class. Most likely you will want to extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` in order to leverage what it already does. I suggest you google "custom listview adapter" or something similar for examples how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example based upon your code that handles clicking a button for each item in the list.

If you click a switch then it displays the id of the item via a toast.

This utilises a Custom Adapter based upon (extends) the CursorAdapter class.

First the layout **adapter.xml** used for the item (should have the basics of your's and includes a switch who's id is the_switch) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/KEYCODE"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NAME"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/the_switch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity **Lights.java** is now :-

```
public class Lights extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView users_list, alt_users_list;
    private DatabaseManager dbManager;
    private MyCustomCursorAdapter adapter;
    //private DatabaseManager dbHelper; //?????? a second not needed
    Cursor cursor;
    Context mContext;

    //<<<<<<<<<< Not needed although could be passed
    //final String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseManager._ID, DatabaseManager.TITLE, DatabaseManager.DESC};
    //final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.KEYCODE, R.id.NAME};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);
        startconnection(); //?????? dummied out
        users_list = findViewById(R.id.users_list);
        alt_users_list = findViewById(R.id.alt_users_list);

        dbManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        manageListView(); //Handles the ListView
    }

    // Moved here handles list refresh if called (e.g. in onResume)
    private void manageListView() {
        cursor = dbManager.fetch();
        //Setup the adapter if not already setup else swaps (refreshes) the cursor
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new MyCustomCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
            users_list.setAdapter(adapter);
            users_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You clicked on the item with an ID of " + String.valueOf(id),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
    private void startconnection(){}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close the Cursors when done with them
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Refresh the listviews when returning to the activity
        manageListView();
    }
}
```

- Comments try to explain changes (basically it is quite similar).
- The biggest change is that the setting up of the listview has been moved to a method of it's own, which also handles refreshing the listview (redisplaying it after the underlying data has been changed).
- The instantiation of the adapter is also simpler than for the SimpleCursorAdapter (the layout and column to view  handling coded in the adapter).

The adapter **myCustomAdapter.java** is :-

```
public class MyCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MyCustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFAAAAFF);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAAAFF);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager._ID)));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.KEYCODE)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.TITLE)));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.NAME)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.DESC)));

        Switch thisswitch = view.findViewById(R.id.the_switch);
        thisswitch.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager._ID)));
        thisswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(),
                        "You clicked the switch for ID " + (String) buttonView.getTag() +
                                " the status is now " + (new Boolean(isChecked)).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                ;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- bindView has primarily been used it :-

  - binds the values from the columns of the cursor to the views for each item
  - and in this case sets the tag of the switch to the id and then adds an onCheckChangedListener for the Button.
- bindView has the advantage that the cursor and context are passed to it.
- getView can also be used, it has the advantage of having the position of the item in the list passed.
- In this case it has been used to alternate the background colour for each item.

## Result

Here's a screen shot showing the toast (note testing data was added to the underlying database, so this will obviously vary from yours) :-

[image]

## Additional

It might be that you need to handle the switch check change in the owning activity.

The following changes show a basic means, via an interface, of handling the switch event in the activity, rather than in the adapter.

First the interface **myOnCheckedChangedInterface.java**

```
public interface myOnCheckedChangedInterface {
    void myOnCheckedChangedHandler(String id, boolean check_status);
}
```

Second change **Lights.java** by adding the handler method **myOnCheckedChangedHandler**

```
@Override
public void myOnCheckedChangedHandler(String id, boolean check_status) {
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "You changed the status for the row with an id of " + id +
                    " the status is now " + new Boolean(check_status).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

- Ignore the error that the method doesn't override method from it's superclass.

Third change the Class declaration to implement the interface by adding `implements myOnCheckedChangedInterface` as per :-

```
public class Lights extends AppCompatActivity implements myOnCheckedChangedInterface {
```

Lastly change MyCustomCursorAdapter to be able to call the myOnCheckedChangedHandler

e.g.

```
public class MyCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    Lights calling_activity; //<<<<<<<<<<@@@@@@@@@@@ ADDED for interface

    public MyCustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
        this.calling_activity = (Lights) context; //<<<<<<<<<<@@@@@@@@@@@ ADDED for interface
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFAAAAFF);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAAAFF);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager._ID)));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.KEYCODE)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.TITLE)));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.NAME)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.DESC)));

        Switch thisswitch = view.findViewById(R.id.the_switch);
        thisswitch.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager._ID)));
        thisswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                /**
                Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(),
                        "You clicked the switch for ID " + (String) buttonView.getTag() +
                                " the status is now " + (new Boolean(isChecked)).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                **/
                calling_activity.myOnCheckedChangedHandler((String)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked); //<<<<<<<<<<@@@@@@@@@@@ ADDED for interface
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- See commments with //<<<<<<<<<<@@@@@@@@@@@ ADDED for interface for changes
- The original Toast has been commented out as it is no longer needed
- Note this isn't the tidiest way as the Adapter is tied to a Lights activity, it's just meant to be a simple example.

Comment: Thanks to you dear. I will do all of your instructions. But first I have two questions. 1. Should i modify fetch () in database class? 2. I have switch  button instead of button you wrote here. Is that in this way again

Comment: @AlirezaMa 1. I don't don't believe you need to (I basically reverse engineered the database class). 2. The code has been modified for a switch (to use  onCheckedChanged Listener). There is no onCheckChanged xml attribute so the additional code has been removed.

Comment: ***Note** to capture the Toast the switch was clicked numerous times thus the message is not representative of the shown state of the switch.*

Comment: Thanks bro. Your tips are working fine but now another problem is the switch can't stay in last position when I scrolling listview. Tnx again

Comment: @AlirezaMa that's because whenever a item has to appear the getView/bindView methods are called the build the view that is now viewable. The value of the switch does come from anywhere (a column in the databsase) so the switch is the default value. What you typically do is update the source of the ListView (the database in this case) to store the state of the switch.

Comment: @AlirezaMa the way StackOverflow is meant to work is that you ask questions about a specific issue, if an answer helps you, you tick that answer. It is not about providing an ongoing service to write/design the code. I believe the above has answered you initial question and that you should therefore tick the answer if you believe it helped you and if you subsequent problems that you then ask other questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize a ListAdapter, you need to create your own custom ListAdapter class that is based on, or 'extends' the built-in ListAdapter (such as SimpleListAdapter or BaseAdapter).  Then, you can customize the appearance and what fields of data to display.  Below is an example of a custom ListAdapter I called ClaimsListAdapter.java that 'extends' the built-in class called BaseAdapter:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.adapter;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import com.mycompany.myapp.ClaimListFragment;
import com.mycompany.myapp.R;
import com.mycompany.myapp.TripListFragment;
import com.mycompany.myapp.model.ClaimItem;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

// You might be able to extend SimpleListAdapter instead if you wish
public class ClaimListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ClaimItem> claimItems;
    ClaimListFragment fragment;

    //I'm passing references to both the active Context as well as the active Fragment
    //You might only need to pass the active Context
    public ClaimListAdapter(ClaimListFragment fragment, Context context, ArrayList<ClaimItem> claimItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.claimItems = claimItems;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return claimItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return claimItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //This is the layout for the list item.  A SimpleListAdapter doesn't need one
            //since it only has one text view, but this allows you to create multiple lines
            //and/or multiple fields, buttons, checkboxes etc if you wish
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list_item, null);
        }

        //Get a reference to all of the items in the layout you wish to change
        Button btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_delete_in_list);
        //Note, here I'm saving the row number in the tag of the button to tell the fragment
        //which row in the array to delete.
        btnDelete.setTag(position);
        //Here is an example of setting a click listener for a button in the list
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
                //Call the Public method in the parent Fragment (or Activity) to delete from the
                //array and refresh the list
                fragment.deleteItemList(position);
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //Get a reference to all of the text fields in the list item
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_title);
        TextView txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_status);
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_date);
        TextView txtDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_distance);
        TextView txtAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_amount);

        String claim_title = claimItems.get(position).getDocumentID();
        String claim_status = claimItems.get(position).getClaimStatus();

        txtTitle.setText(claim_title);
        txtStatus.setText(claim_status);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And the claim_list_item.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/whole_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.48"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/claim_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.73"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/claim_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.48"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/claim_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/claim_distance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/claim_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/claim_delete_in_list"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```